# How to set up a machine learning model with no data

Tags: machine-learning, python

I know what you're thinking. This is a silly question. I think so too but our company is very young and has almost no data whatsoever to train the model. I'm assigned to just set up a model infrastructure to take inputs and output decision (doesn't have to be accurate for now). When we have the infrastructure in place, we will look into collecting or buying data to feed through the model.

In my opinion, this process is kinda backward but it's the way my boss wants it so I gotta deliver.

My goal is to build a machine learning model (random forest, boosting, logistic regression,etc.) for a set of features as followed:
- Target: binary
- Features: A (binary), B (categorical with 4 classes), C (numeric), D (binary)

As I have no training data, I can't follow the traditional route of splitting train/test, fit, cross validate, and arrive at the optimal model. How do I simply arrive at a model with dummy coefficients without training it? I will then serialize the ML model into a pickle file to plug it in a Flask app to give decision. Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you know what the data will look like? If so, just create a fake data set.

Comment: I would have a read of this: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/rules-of-ml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just write unit tests.**

The scenario you're describing may not be that uncommon. For example, when a team works on putting machine learning algorithm into production, they may divide the tasks between several developers, e.g. someone prepares data preprocessing pipeline, someone else the machine learning model prototype, etc. In such scenario you may need to write some code before gathering all the needed data.

What you can do in such case, is to follow the test-driven development approach, and start with writing series of unit tests for your code. Since you don't have data, just [mock](https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/) it. Mocking is creating objects that preserve face-value features of the real life objects (functions, methods, APIs, data) that are passed through your code as if they were real objects. For mocking the data you would just fill the files (database etc) with random data of similar properties, so if you have "age" in your input data, the values would be non-negative, years rather would be in thousands, categorical data would have few distinct categories etc. Then proceed as if this was real data and write unit tests followed by the code, so that the tests would assure you the code works as expected.

*This won't help you* with testing if the model would be able to give any meaningful results, since it would train on random data. It would help you with preparing the prototype code that "works".

Answer (score 0):

I would say simply initialize the model's weights at random. Which type the different features of your data are doesn't really make a difference here, as in any case you'd have to convert all of them to the same type (typically float) before feeding them to your model.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how model inputs will be converted to the same type? 

I usually label encode or one-hot encode categorical variables and leave numerical variables as is. Then I would split the data and run function .fit()

Comment: Just like you've said, categorical variables need to be converted in numerical form based on whether they are ordinal (meaning that there exists an ordering among the different values that the feature could have, in which case it makes sense to label encode them) or not (in which case you must one-hot encode them). Numerical variables can be left as they are, although it is usually better to convert integer variables to floating point, as the model's weights are going to be of type float.

Answer (score 0):

One way addressing problems where you have little(or no data) is 'replacing' it with priors.
Bayesian modeling has the priors concept at its core.
If your using python take a look at [pymc](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/)(and start off as simple as you can).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of overreaching, I think you're putting the cart before the horse. Your startup has objectives but no data. The question you really need to answer is: "If my company had data, would it even make a difference?" Unless your companies business model is 100% ML driven, most likely its growth objectives are not initially dependent on strong ML solutions to its problems. ML makes a difference only when you have a *consistent*, large and high-quality set of features. Whereas your company will be launching and removing new features at a breakneck pace.

So, instead of wasting time setting up infrastructure, focus instead on brainstorming the kinds of problems your company expects to solve with data when it does have it. This means working with the product and engineering teams to ensure you are correctly and accurately collecting features for each of your companies verticals. The engineering team's job is to quickly and efficiently deliver features but your job is to make sure that those features are actionable. This means that you need to ensure that their storage and delivery is up to spec for the kind of ML you want to do (for example, how long of a delay between updates is desired?). It also means clearly defining objectives, e.g. KPIs. Whatever ML infrastructure that you build will start at this source of those features and KPIs, and if you get it wrong, it will all be for naught.